# Root galaxy note without extern devices, software or internet

Tags: rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, root-access, samsung-galaxy-note

Hi I wondering if I can root my phone (Jelly bean 4.1.2) without computer or else. I want to root it man manually by myself, in other words without any apps or something.

Also, if is possible to root without any zip-packs or additional downloads.

Now I have just a fresh installed andriod, no updates or apps installed, also no google account on it. Now I want to root it without anything or internet access.

Comment: If you want to root your device you have to either use a computer or download an APK file trough your android browser.

Comment: How exactly to you propose to accomplish this without any external downloads whatsoever? You're basically asking how to build a house, but without any tools, equipment, or lumber. The process requires at least a minimal set of supplies to even be possible.

Comment: As I know: Rooting is just switching to the admin mode of the operating system. And for that I usually do not need other devices, internet or software. On Ubuntu and other linux distribution I can also easily switch to root mode without anything? Andriod is linux?

Comment: Yes, Android is based on Linux but it is locked down by Google and possibly your carrier because if you accidentally brick or break your device they don't want to be responsible for that. Rooting basically means that you exploit a vulnerablity in Android and unlock the root account.

Comment: Android simply isn't designed that way. If it was, then the external tools and hackery wouldn't have a reason to exist. What you're hoping to do is not possible unless you manage to find some kind of huge security vulnerability that's locally exploitable with only the pre-installed apps (and if there was such an exploit, I would expect that someone would have found it by now).

Answer (score 1):

Simply enough: no, there is not. You absolutely, positively will need outside resources. You will need outside tools downloaded to a computer, a USB connection to it, and data pushed to it. The bare minimum that would be possible, which is still not possible with the Note as far as I'm aware, could be rooting it from the phone with downloaded apps that exploit security holes to get through. But again, that would still require Internet and outside tools. There is no way in Android to root without that. It's not like straight Linux where you can visit a CLI and type a few commands and you're there. It's locked down to prevent that.